# How can I split string by space and also the double quotes in php

Tags: php

I have string as below

```
$data = 1hs: "1 U.S. dollar", rhs: "29.892653 Taiwan dollars"
```

I want to split the string with only spaces and double quotes so that I can get the array like this:

```
$data[ ]= 29.892653  <--- the most important part I would like to get. 
$data[ ]= Taiwan dollars <--- not sure is it possible to do this?
```

so far I use the code below

```
$data = preg_split("/[,\s]*[^\w\s]+[\s]*/", $data,0,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

but it returns only the 29 and split all marks including '.'

Comment: So you essentially want to split a number, and then a string?

Comment: And as a general note, be as specific as possible with your regex, if you don't NEED to use a \s and a \d will work, don't use the \s

Comment: You don't have a string there, technically I'm not sure what that is, but it isn't a string (no opening or ending quotes, not sure what is part of the parsed string you're wanting and what isn't).

Comment: `preg_split` is sometimes confused with `preg_match_all`

Answer (score 1):

This regex will pull everything out for you into nicely named array fields.

```
$data = '1hs: "1 U.S. dollar", rhs: "29.892653 Taiwan dollars"';

// Using named capturing groups for easier reference in the code
preg_match_all(
    '/(?P<prefix>[^,\s:]*):\s"(?P<amount>[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)\s(?P<type>[^"]*)"/', 
    $data, 
    $matches, 
    PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach($matches as $match) {
    // This is the full matching string
    echo "Matched this: " . $match[0] . "<br />";

    // These are the friendly named pieces
    echo 'Prefix: ' . $match['prefix'] . "<br />";
    echo 'Amount: ' . $match['amount'] . "<br />";
    echo 'Type: ' . $match['type'] . "<br />";
}
```

Outputs:

- Matched this: 1hs: "1 U.S. dollar"
- Prefix: 1hs
- Amount: 1
- Type: U.S. dollar

And:

- Matched this: rhs: "29.892653 Taiwan dollars"
- Prefix: rhs
- Amount: 29.892653
- Type: Taiwan dollars

Comment: It works well! Thanks for the answer. It is really neat, organized and readable. I have been stuck on the problem for two days. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should first fetch a number formatted as < number>[.< number>], and then take everything after that as a second group which should match your description unless there are some special cases not visible in your question.

```
preg_match('/([0-9]+\.{0,1}[0-9]*)\s+(.*?)/', $data, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and response. This problem is solved. I think this preg_match function is totally a brand new function for me to pick up.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one line with string functions assuming the format is always the same

```
$string = '1hs: "1 U.S. dollar", rhs: "29.892653 Taiwan dollars"';
$data = explode(' ', trim(substr($string, strrpos($string, ':')+2), '"'),2);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help though the version I used seems not support  var_dump function. The problem is solved.